# how to access protected variables in child class php5

Tags: php, oop

```
<?php
class a
{
    protected $c=10;

}
class b extends a{

    echo a::$c;

    }
    //$obj = new b();

?>
```

Here I am trying to print the parent class variable in the child class. can you tell me how to make use of the parent class variables in child class in PHP5?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please show your code.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking, but did you look at the official manual?

Comment: Have a look over [http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
class parent {
    protected $field;
}
class child extends parent {
  public function test() {
    return $this->field;
  }
}
```

Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php